# Error cannot find symbol variable CalligraphyContextWrapper al actualizar a Android 3.4

Tags: java, android-studio

Acabé de actualizar Android Studio a 3.4 y me comenzó a generar varios errores al intentar compilar la aplicación:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable CalligraphyContextWrapper
error: package CalligraphyConfig does not exist
error: cannot find symbol variable CalligraphyConfig
```

> Librería

```
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
```

Agradezco su colaboración.

```
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Before setContentView
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                                              .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.ttf")
                                              .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                                              .build());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Comment: Buenvenido. Por favor, añade el código relevante al error para poder buscar cuál podría ser el problema. Comprueba [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) cómo preguntar correctamente.

Comment: Ya intentaste Clean Project - Rebuild Project ?

Comment: Ya lo utilice y me soluciono el problema, muchas gracias